# Is there a built-in method to parse the fault out of a Message in .NET?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF client that is calling an arbitrary SOAP endpoint in which the endpoint returns an Soap Message (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message).  If that message is a fault, is there any built-in .NET class that will deserialize it into either a SoapFault or FaultException or do I just need to parse the message manually?

The raw message is as follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:59da9d2e-2b96-4fc8-8105-1907a0ce6584</a:RelatesTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <s:Code>
        <s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
        <s:Subcode>
          <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</s:Value>
        </s:Subcode>
      </s:Code>
      <s:Reason>
        <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">Something is Amiss!</s:Text>
      </s:Reason>
      <s:Detail>
        <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
          <InnerException i:nil="true" />
          <Message>Something is Amiss!</Message>
          <StackTrace>   at Rhino.Mocks.Expectations.AbstractExpectation.ReturnOrThrow(IInvocation invocation, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.DoMethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.Invocation.Actions.RegularInvocation.PerformAgainst(IInvocation invocation)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.MockXCARespondingGatewayProxyde8c39af35f14e839b4be7dfba3abf0f.CrossGatewayQuery(Message request)
   at SyncInvokeCrossGatewayQuery(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
          <Type>System.Exception</Type>
        </ExceptionDetail>
      </s:Detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try feeding the message to [`MessageFault.CreateFault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344799.aspx) - according to [this](http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2010/12/wcf-parse-fault-from-raw-message.html) it can parse a fault out of a given message...

Comment: Awesome, thanks Yahia.  I figured something had to exist if I knew where to look.